# How to tether a bridge camera that cannot be tethered

Tags: video-streaming

I need live video from my Nikon P510 on a screen different from the LCD one the camera has.

First thing is, I can stream video from the camera to a TV as it is shown here: https://youtu.be/u2zLBrf0O8E

I want to do the exact same thing with my computer.

I have checked this thread: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/79257/can-i-get-liveview-from-my-nikon-coolpix-p600-on-my-computer

But as it says, Coolpix Pxxx series does not allow "tethering".

I want to ask if there is any way to make the stream possible as if my computer was the TV of the video above.

Comment: If you can stream that way to a TV, you just need to get a video capture device (grabber) and you're done.   Duckduckgo let me pick one:  https://www.amazon.com/Top-Longer-Capture-Support-Windows-Grabber/dp/B01MQGMHXD?SubscriptionId=AKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q&tag=duckduckgo-d-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01MQGMHXD

Comment: Ok I like that.